# Does the catechism teach not to kill animals for food?

Tags: catholicism, diet, catholic-catechism

The Catechism teaches that we “owe” animals “kindness.”

> 2457 Animals are entrusted to man's stewardship; he must show them
> kindness. They may be used to serve the just satisfaction of man's
> needs.

[Reference.](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c2a7.htm)

Does this mean we shouldn't kill animals for our food? Or what does the "just satisfaction" mean in this statement?

Comment: Are you asking if good Catholics can eat meat?

Comment: Have you bothered to look up the term you are asking about?  As to your question, if you have not found the passage "don't kill animals for food" then why would you expect the Catechism to teach it? (Hint, you won't find that statement as you asked it).  The Catechism is on line, at the Vatican web site, and is searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have quoted I would say that we can kill animals for food.

"Just satisfaction" meaning to satisfy our reasonable needs - e.g., we need food to live.

That we need to treat them kindly speaks to how they are allowed to live and that we "dispatch" them with out causing pain or distress.

This, in my opinion, affects the eggs and chickens we buy - an industrial form of agriculture that has seen much ill-treatment of the animal in the name of profit.

Comment: do you have any reference to what the "Just satisfaction" means?

Comment: I don't think either word means anything other than what they commonly mean.

Comment: @Grasper It is my opinion. The official teaching is what you quoted.  I was simply trying to explain the official teaching and add real world examples.